# Data table - Apex refresh is not working in lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, datatable

Apex Refresh is not working, Can any one please help me on this.

```
import { refreshApex } from "@salesforce/apex";
```

JS

```
@wire(getParentGuardian, { EnrollmentId: "E0008" })
enroll({ data, error }) {
this.wiredDataResultRefresh = data;
if (data) {
  let mapped = data.map(row => [
    {
      firstName: row.Father_First_Name__c,
      lastName: row.Father_Last_Name__c,
      email: row.Father_Email__c,
      cell: row.Father_Cell__c
    },
    {
      firstName: row.Mother_First_Name__c,
      lastName: row.Mother_Last_Name__c,
      email: row.Mother_Email__c,
      cell: row.Mother_Cell__c
    }
  ]);
  this.wiredDataResult = mapped.flat();      
} else if (error) {
  this.error = error;
  this.parameters = undefined;
}
}

refreshData() {
return refreshApex(enroll(this.wiredDataResult));
// return refreshApex(enroll);
}
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing  class GetParentGuardianController {

@AuraEnabled (cacheable = true)
public static List<Enrollment__c> getParentGuardian(String EnrollmentId) {      

    system.debug('ENROL ' + EnrollmentId);      

  return   [select  Id, Father_First_Name__c, Father_Last_Name__c, Father_Email__c, Father_Cell__c
                              ,Mother_First_Name__c ,Mother_Last_Name__c, Mother_Email__c, Mother_Cell__c
                              from Enrollment__c WHERE Name=:EnrollmentId];

     // return ls; 

}    
}
```

Comment: try using refreshApex(this.wiredDataResult);

Answer (score 6):

This is a simple mistake of not using the entire response object, but instead trying to use just one of its properties.

Instead of:

```
@wire(getParentGuardian, { EnrollmentId: "E0008" })
enroll({ data, error }) {
    this.wiredDataResultRefresh = data;

    ...
```

You MUST do the following:

```
@wire(getParentGuardian, { EnrollmentId: "E0008" })
enroll(response) {
    this.wiredDataResultRefresh = response;
    const data = response.data;
    const error = response.error;

    ...
```

You'll then call the refresh using:

```
refreshApex(this.wiredDataResultRefresh);
```

Without providing the complete response obtained the Apex Refresh mechanism has no way to map back to the cache.